# Rails easyist way to create hash with certain attributes and also nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
  def search
  @sog = Konkurrencer.where("titel like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  @kate = []
  @sog.each do |kat|
    h = {}
    kat.attributes.each{|k,v| h[k] = v.respond_to?(:force_encoding) ? v.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") : v }
    @kate << h
  end
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @kate }
  end
```

The problem is that the JSON contains all the attributes for the model. How do I create a JSON that have only ID, url and titel?

The JSON should also contain the key "url" which key should be the URL for the associated photo. I use paperclip. The path is: `@konkurrencer.photo.image.url`

**UPDATE:**
My search.json.erb:

```
[
<% @sog.each do |kon| %>
{"id":"<%= kon.id %>","titel":"<%= kon.titel %>"},
<% end %>
]
```

How do I remove the , for the last loop?

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with the list of attributes you want to display. Use `select` query method to get only this fields in the SQL request. And finally loop on this attributes to fill the JSON array:

```
def search
  displayed_attributes = %w{id url titel}

  @sog = Konkurrencer.select(displayed_attributes.join(',')).where("titel like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  @kate = []
  @sog.each do |kat|
    h = {}
    displayed_attributes.each do |attribute| 
       v = kat[attribute]
       h[attribute] = v.respond_to?(:force_encoding) ? v.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") : v
    end
    @kate << h
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @kate }
  end
end
```